# Admob ads with Unity on Android Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, apk

Having the hardest time trying to get admob ads to work.

I have my device added as a test device and I can get ads working when installing and running my apk through Android Studio. I'm using the profile and debug apk setting.

I uploaded the same apk to developer console and released it under the 'internal testing'. When I install the app through the testers link, ads don't work.

Has anyone ran into this issue and found a fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rate of Admob getting failed is an issue in my country so I always test Admob with a VPN. Try Hotspot shield or any other VPN. It works for me.